# Gatsby and netlify - npm run start got error with cover_image

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

https://medium.com/@d3vma/build-a-blog-portfolio-with-reacts-gatsby-and-netlify-cms-fc1bee6451a5

I follow above tutorial to make a Gatsby and Netlify website, but I got error message below for a custom type in Frontmatter, thanks.

```
ERROR #85923  GRAPHQL

There was an error in your GraphQL query:

Cannot query field "cover_image" on type "Frontmatter".

If you don't expect "cover_image" to exist on the type "Frontmatter" it is most likely a typo.
However, if you expect "cover_image" to exist there are a couple of solutions to common problems:

- If you added a new data source and/or changed something inside gatsby-node.js/gatsby-config.js, please try a restart of your development server
- The field might be accessible in another subfield, please try your query in GraphiQL and use the GraphiQL explorer to see which fields you can query and what  
shape they have
- You want to optionally use your field "cover_image" and right now it is not used anywhere. Therefore Gatsby can't infer the type and add it to the GraphQL     
schema. A quick fix is to add at least one entry with that field ("dummy content")

It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want to use optional fields. This way you don't have to add the mentioned "dummy content". Visit 
our docs to learn how you can define the schema for "Frontmatter":
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/graphql-data-layer/schema-customization#creating-type-definitions

File: src\pages\index.js:98:9

failed extract queries from components - 3.793s
success write out requires - 0.105s
success run static queries - 0.051s - 2/2 39.01/s
success run page queries - 0.039s - 2/2 51.62/s
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 14427ms                                                                                                                  10:01:51⠀
 I  Netlify CMS is running at http://localhost:8000/admin/

 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed


C:\Users\nosy_\Desktop\React\gatsme\src\pages\index.js
  98:9  error  Cannot query field "cover_image" on type "Frontmatter"  graphql/template-strings

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


failed Building development bundle - 28.582s
ERROR in
C:\Users\nosy_\Desktop\React\gatsme\src\pages\index.js
  98:9  error  Cannot query field "cover_image" on type "Frontmatter"  graphql/template-strings

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


webpack compiled with 1 error
```

And these is other parts related to cover_image. In Config.yml, under collections, fields:

{ label: 'Cover Image', name: 'cover_image', widget: 'image', required: false }

In index.js

```
return (
  ...
    <GatsbyImage
       image={post.frontmatter.cover_image?.childImageSharp?.gatsbyImageData}
       className="h-72 w-full gatsby-bg-image rounded mb-3"
       alt={title} />
  ...)
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? Does it build locally?

Comment: yes it is built locally

Comment: Can you also provide the data structure or more details?

Comment: @Ferran Buireu  I have added more details, please check,thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a lack of details, implementation and structure in your question but, assuming that the project is building locally. I would try to force the same Node version in both environments (Netlify and locally).

Run in the root of your project:

```
node -v > .nvmrc
```

This will create a `.nvmrc` file containing your local Node version. Netlify, at the deployment time, will take that version to build the project, forcing the environment to work in the same working version as your local does.